# Flutter Error when add firebase admin sdk: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-admin

When i add firebase admin and path to json file,
a bug could't fix:

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    var cred = FirebaseAdmin.instance.certFromPath('admin-services.json');
    print(cred.toString());
    FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp(
            AppOptions(
                credential: cred,
                databaseUrl: databaseURL,
            ),
    );
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
            options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[code_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDWRl.png)

bug here:

```
E/flutter (16111): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FirebaseAppError(app/invalid-credential): Failed to parse certificate key file: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'admin-services.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (16111): #0      new ServiceAccountCredential credential.dart:97
E/flutter (16111): #1      FirebaseAdmin.certFromPath   admin.dart:113
E/flutter (16111): #2      main main.dart:14
E/flutter (16111): #3      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:131:23)
E/flutter (16111): #4      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:296:19)
E/flutter (16111): #5      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

[debug_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir6nA.png)

I tried to move file, even use absolute path to json file or other way but also receive bug:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var cred = FirebaseAdmin.instance.cert(projectId: projectId, 
      clientEmail: clientEmail, 
      privateKey: privateKey);
  print(cred.toString());
  FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp(
    AppOptions(
      credential: cred,
      databaseUrl: databaseURL,
    ),
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[code_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7V7.png)

bug:

```
E/flutter (15745): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError
E/flutter (15745): #0      FirebaseAdmin.cert admin.dart:108
E/flutter (15745): #1      main main.dart:14
E/flutter (15745): #2      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:131:23)
E/flutter (15745): #3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:296:19)
E/flutter (15745): #4      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

[bug_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Q3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move it under android/app. You can check this [sample_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjxtc.png)

Comment: i know but this json file 'google-services.json' is different with json file 'admin-services.json' which contain private key i use to add firebase admin sdk to my project.

Comment: Okay for that you have to use google cloud console. Refer this video - [android-sdk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXOzbKDXTh0&ab_channel=%E1%91%95%E1%96%87%E1%97%A9%E4%B9%99%C6%B3%E1%91%95%E1%97%9D%E1%97%AA%E1%97%B4%E1%96%87)